# Is there a way to check for a MOUSBUTTONDOWN event given a list of Rect objects?

Tags: python, pygame, rect

I'm making a game for my final project for class and for some reason I can't check for a click event on a rect object when it's in a list. If i iterate through the Opened_Pack list using a for loop and try to click on it, then nothing happens (This is the code I have below). When I try it using an index ([0], [1], etc) then there's an Index Out of Range Error, no matter what number I use or how big the list is. So i guess my question is: is there a way I can check if i clicked on a rect if that data is stored in a list? There has to be, i'm sure, but I cannot figure it out.

```
Opened_Pack = []
Pack_Card_Recs = []

for event in pygame.event.get():
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            window = pygame.display.set_mode((850,850), pygame.RESIZABLE)
            #Key Bindings to open Packs, WILL BE REPLACED WITH CLICKS (eventually)
        if event.key == pygame.K_r:
            Opened_Pack = TwoPlayerPack.Open()
            Pack_Card_Recs = [Opened_Pack[i].getRect() for i in range(len(Opened_Pack))]
            #print(Pack_Card_Recs[0])
        elif event.key == pygame.K_e:
            Opened_Pack= SixPlayerPack.Open()
            Pack_Card_Recs = [Opened_Pack[i].getRect() for i in range(len(Opened_Pack))]
        elif event.key == pygame.K_t:
            Opened_Pack = SevenPlayerPack.Open()
            Pack_Card_Recs = [Opened_Pack[i].getRect() for i in range(len(Opened_Pack))]
        elif event.key == pygame.K_u:
            Opened_Pack= FourPlayerPack.Open()
            Pack_Card_Recs = [Opened_Pack[i].getRect() for i in range(len(Opened_Pack))]

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        x, y = event.pos
        for i in range(len(Opened_Pack)):
            if Pack_Card_Recs[i].collidepoint(x,y):
                print("Clicked Player at index: " + str(i))

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
```

Comment: If you have found the solution then publish as an answer, do not edit your question or add FIXED in the title.

Answer (score 3):

The code is iterating for the length of `Opened_Pack`, whereas the rectangles in question are stored in the list `Pack_Card_Recs`.  Simply modifiyng the loop range should fix it.

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    x, y = event.pos
    print( "%d rectangles to check" % ( len( Pack_Card_Recs ) ) )
    for i in range( len( Pack_Card_Recs ) ):             # <-- HERE, not Opened_Pack
        r = Pack_Card_Recs[i]
        print( "Is point (%d, %d) inside Rect #%d [%d, %d, %d x %d]" % ( x, y, i, r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height ) )
        if r.collidepoint( x,y ):
            print( "Clicked Player at index: " + str( i ) )
```

EDIT: Added a bunch of debug code

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer but now I'm back to the same problem. After editing, theres no output, which is the same thing that happened when i had it as len(Opened_Pack).

Comment: @Scott - run with debug, if that doesn't help, add the debug output to the question text.

Comment: after using the updated debug code, the only thing being printed is "0 rectangles to check" after i click on any of the rects, nothing else in any other situation

Comment: @Scott - Check what your functions `FourPlayerPack.Open()` etc. are returning.  Why is the list of rectangles empty?  It could also be because none of the events have fired yet.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the lists are created INSIDE the main while loop so, obviously, every frame the game updates the lists are recreated. I just moved them outside the main loop and it works just fine now.